# How to show custom number of records on a TcxGrid

Tags: delphi, tcxgrid

I'm trying to show just 1000 records from a query that has 100k+ records on a TcxGrid from the DeveloperExpress VCL V2011 Vol 2.4, I just found on internet that you can use a grid property on DBGridTableView -> DataController -> GridMode, setting it to True (In design) and Choosing the GridModeBufferCount number of records to show, but It didn't work, it keeps showing all data when I execute the program linked with that grid, what I'm doing wrong? or is there any option to show high amount of data on a grid? (To be exported using ExportGridToExcel function).

Comment: If you want to show only 1000 records then query 1000 records. GridMode on means retrieve enough rows to fill the visible grid and retrieve more as needed, With GridMode off all rows are retrieved so client side features like sorting, filtering, grouping etc work.  In both cases all the rows can be navigated to.

Comment: I mean, I want to show just 1000 records to make the process faster, (client doesn't mind on checking all 100k+ records on execution)  but then I want to Export those 100k + records to Excel using the Function ExportGridToExcel (Assuming I can get those 100k+ records on a excel file just loading 1000 on the grid)